# Why is ref.watch(otherProvider.stream) deprecated in Riverpod 2.x and will be removed in 3.x?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm using Riverpod to listen to changes to a selected item from my store:

1. I have a repository `PlacesStore` which has a `Stream<PlaceDetails?> watchPlace(PlaceId placeId)` method.
2. I have wrapped this in a family provider like so:

   ```dart
   @riverpod
   Stream<PlaceDetails?> place(PlaceRef ref, InternalPlaceId placeId) {
       final store = ref.watch(placesStoreProvider);
       return store.watchPlace(placeId);
   }
   ```
3. I have a separate `StateProvider`, `selectedPlaceIdProvider`, which is updated with  a place ID of a place the user selects on the map.
4. I have another provider, `selectedPlaceProvider`, which combines both like this:

   ```dart
   @riverpod
   Stream<PlaceDetails?> selectedPlace(SelectedPlaceRef ref) {
       final placeId = ref.watch(selectedPlaceIdProvider);
       if (placeId != null) {
           return ref.watch(placeProvider(placeId).stream);
       }

       return const Stream.empty();
    }
   ```

I was doing it like this because I have a number of widgets which want to know what place the user has selected, so I thought it made sense to pull that into a provider which contains the currently selected place details (while still maintaining the family provider so adhoc places can be looked up).

However, when using `ref.watch(placeProvider(placeId).stream)` I am warned that `.stream` is deprecated. I don't quite follow what I am meant to replace it with.

Is the above pattern valid? And if so, what do I replace `.stream` with so I can still listen to any changes to my currently selected place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.stream` modifier has been deprecated because it almost always was badly used, leading to complex hard-to-spot bugs.

The very snippet you gave in this question faces the same issue. The snippet you gave has a bug:

```dart
@riverpod
Stream<PlaceDetails?> selectedPlace(SelectedPlaceRef ref) {
    final placeId = ref.watch(selectedPlaceIdProvider);
    if (placeId != null) {
        return ref.watch(placeProvider(placeId).stream);
    }

    return const Stream.empty();
}
```

In this snippet, the usage of `.stream` introduces a problem where now the behavior of `selectedPlace` depends on the order in which your providers are read.

Say you did:

```dart
void main() async {
  final container = ProviderContainer();
  final place = await container.read(placeProvider(123).future);

  container.read(selectedPlaceIdProvider.notifier).state = 123;
  container.listen(selectedPlaceProvider, (_, value) {
    print('Place $value');
  });
}
```

Then in this scenario, you'll find that the `print` is in fact never reached, and `selectedPlace` never emits anything.
But if you were to comment out the `final place = await container.read(placeProvider(123).future);` line, then your code would "work".

That effectively means using `.stream` introduced a race condition. It's very hard to spot unless you're familiar with the issue, and can cause significant maintainability problems.

On the flip side of things, having `.stream` doesn't add much value to Riverpod. You can already do everything without `.stream`.

The Changelog that introduced the deprecation gives alternate syntaxes to your usage https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/packages/riverpod/CHANGELOG.md#230

In your case, you could refactor `selectedPlaceProvider` to:

```dart
@riverpod
Future<PlaceDetails?> selectedPlace(SelectedPlaceRef ref) {
    final placeId = ref.watch(selectedPlaceIdProvider);
    if (placeId == null) return null;

    return ref.watch(placeProvider(placeId).future);
}
```

This snippet behave like you would expect the .stream variant to behave. In that scenario, `selectedPlace` will update whenever either `placeProvider` or `selectedPlaceIdProvider` update.
But at the same time, this doesn't involve the race-condition problem discussed above. That `main` wrote previously would now work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Rémi, your race condition example hadn't occurred to me but now makes a lot of sense. Appreciate you providing support for your great library here! Marking this answer as accepted.


I assume this `FutureProvider` will transition to a `AsyncLoading` state whenever the `selectedPlaceIdProvider` changes, assuming that `placeProvider` did not have the value cached. Subsequent stream updates to that `placeProvider` would just trigger it to receive a new `AsyncValue`? (I will play around with this tonight).

Answer (score 3):

You really never need a stream from a provider.  If you want a view or a provider to depend on other provider changes, simply subscribe with `ref.watch` or `ref.listen`.

Streams have no place in state management.  Streams are useful for places where having every single intermediate state is important to record, like a log or a bank transaction ledger. But in state management, having the *latest* value is all that's important.  You merely need your view or your provider to consume the other provider's latest value, and you're done.

And `.stream` was removed, because it made some other parts of the code difficult.  If you actually need a stream, you can listen to a provider, and generate your own stream using your rules.